# MY SQL insert syntax error

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

I know what a syntax error is but i cant find the problem in my syntax. I did the sql in phpmyadmin first and not ive just copied and put variables in.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's new carving chisels. 1 x 13mm 4-point finishing claw Chisel.
>   Southern St' at line 3

Code:

```
public function insert_row($vendor, $product_link, $product_title, $product_desc, $product_price){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `crawl_products` ( `vendor` , `product_link` , `product_title` , `product_desc` , `product_price` )
        VALUES (
        '$vendor', '$product_link', '$product_title', '$product_desc', '$product_price'
        )") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape your user input.

Comment: Error is coming due to the fact that you have single quote in your data. You should use mysql_real_escape_string like function before concating values. Better use mysqli and binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `mysql_real_escape_string` over each variable before running the insert query

```
public function insert_row($vendor, $product_link, $product_title, $product_desc, $product_price){

    $vendor = mysql_real_escape_string($vendor);
    $product_link = mysql_real_escape_string($product_link);
    $product_title = mysql_real_escape_string($product_title);
    $product_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($product_desc);
    $product_price = mysql_real_escape_string($product_price);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `crawl_products` ( `vendor` , `product_link` , `product_title` , `product_desc` , `product_price` )
        VALUES (
        '$vendor', '$product_link', '$product_title', '$product_desc', '$product_price'
        )") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tables need no Grave accents, e.g. "`vendor`" should just be "vendor", and try to write the variables like this:

```
VALUES ( '".$vendor."',
```

it should work then.

And what sythnet wrote about `mysql_query($con` applies to mysqli_qurey, not to mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

Escape the inputs. Use **[mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)**.

---

Also have look at : [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1288198)